# Migrate videos from Vimeo to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, vimeo-api

I have a large quantity of videos on my Vimeo account that I would like to migrate to my AWS S3 account.

Rather than go through the time consuming process of downloading from Vimeo to my local machine then uploading from my local machine to S3, is there a way where I can do a direct transfer from Vimeo to S3?

If possible, I would want to create a script to iterate through each video via Vimeo API and set up the path to where it would go into S3 then initiate a direct transfer.  Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is not the best answer, but a quick way is to spin up an EC2 instance in the same region as your bucket and then download to EC2 and then upload to S3. This will provide you with high speed data transfer in both directions. Just don't pick a T2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PRO account or higher, you can use the API to get download links for videos on your account, including download links for the original source file. Those download file links should be able to be used for importing into S3. Note that the links provided via the Vimeo API are expiring HTTP 302 redirects to the video file resource, so make sure you take note of the expiration time also provided in the response.

Download links are returned with the rest of a video's metadata, so I suggest using the fields parameter to only return the metadata needed.

http://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#GET/users/{user_id}/videos

Comment: Hi, how I'll use the Vimeo download file links for importing in S3?